# What are callbacks doing in omniauth-facebook integration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, omniauth

Documentation on `omniauth-facebook` mentions callbacks a lot, but I don't see callbacks inside the documentation, and I didn't need to write any callbacks (in the Javascript sense I'm used to) to make the authentication work.

Documentation: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

**For example:**

> By clicking on the above link, the user will be redirected to
>   Facebook. (If this link doesn't exist, try restarting the server.)
>   After inserting their credentials, they will be redirected back to
>   your application's callback method.

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

**Callbacks Controller**

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

I don't see any explicitly written callbacks here so I assume there is something going on behind the scenes.

But I'm kind of confused - what are the callbacks actually doing and what part of this code is a callback?

Apologies in advance if this is a super newbie question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A callback in OmniAuth is the return url where the user is redirected after authentication - its the endpoint where the external service *calls your application back*. The term "callback" is quite frequently used this way when it comes to server side programming.

So in this case `Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook` is the 'callback' handler for this authentication provider.

This is quite a different concept than the JavaScript concept of callbacks which is event oriented programming by passing functions around.

Comment: `Callback handler` just means the part of the code that redirects the user?

Comment: No, is just a regular controller action which Facebook redirects back to after the authorization dialog.